# Login to multiple servers and run a command having passphrase

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Already passphrase has been setup and now I want to login to multiple servers and run a command against all of the servers. I tried this

```
#! /bin/bash
for HOST in $(cat servers.txt ) ; do
ssh -o $HOST "uname -a" PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
done
```

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I would try cannonical order

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no \
    -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password \
     $HOST "uname -a"
```

using your command, ssh will interpret `PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no` as argument to be sent to remote host.

---

In order to use ssh to connect to a remote host, 3 main solutions are used.

## 1) remote's password

plain and obvious, you enter remote host's password each time.
Pros : no setup 
Cons : password to be entered each time

## 2) password less key pair

you must generate a pair of private/public key without password, deploy public key in remote account.
Pros : no password to enter 
Cons : key can be stolen

## 3) password protected key pair

you must generate a pair of private/public key with a password, deploy public key in remote account. You can either load key in memory (`ssh-agent`) or enter password key every time.
Pros : key can't be stolen 
Cons : password to be entered or load/unload

I was not able to find which kind of connection you use. I assume that in the "`ssha host`" in your comment "a" is a typo. Since your are using the word "Passphrase" I assumed you set a password on private key, as it is the expression used.

my next guess is for you to try

```
ssh $HOST uname -a
```

Comment: its the same error i get....first or second it treates same way .....

Comment: Also , here i want to bypass passphrase and login to the servers and run command against it

Comment: 1) can you edit the post with the error "the same error" is difficult to interpret.

Comment: 2) you explicitly requires interactive authentification `-o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password` and disable public key `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no` can you be more precise on this point ?

Comment: There was already passphrase setup done ,After loading passphrase, i can able to login to the server by doing "ssha host" but when i run the script it is asking for password which it should not.

Comment: can you edit your post with 1) a log of a successfull connection 2) a log of a unsuccessfull connection ?

Comment: Successfully login - > Loading the keys and giving passphrase  -> ssha host = Perfect   unsuccessfull login -> that is with in this script as given it will ask for password    #! /bin/bash
for HOST in $(cat servers.txt ) ; do
#ssh $HOST uptime
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes $HOST "uname -a"
done

Comment: i got the solution - > when i run the script it is creating subshell and looking for passphrase to give again , When you run the script....you have to give in this fashion ".  ./script.sh" this will avoid in creating subshell which will run smoothly.